# How to add new Strings to a certain array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, addition

I got 4 arrays in my code and everytime a user writes something into the edittext I want to store that string in one of the array, I tried to use the toCharArray method but I don't know how to define the array where the string should be put in :S

```
String [] array7 = {"Hey","Was Up","Yeahh"};
    TextView txtV1,txtV2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layouttry);
        txtV1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtV2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);



        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = extras.getString("Key");  // this value I want to add to the stringarray
```

Comment: Some code would sure make this question make sense.

Comment: He meant it. Your question is not clear, copy and paste your code into the question or at least try to be more specific - what type are the arrays, how would you decide what array each string goes to etc.

Comment: You don't know who down-voted your question. It may have been someone else. It is part of this site and happens to everyone. Even me... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add new elements I would suggest replacing your arrays with ArrayLists. This will let you use the `add` method to insert new elements. An example of this:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("Text here");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I can only see one array on Strings, so I'm not sure about what you actually need. I'll try my best though.

Your String array is hard-coded to have only three cells in it, and they are all full. If you want to put the string into any of these places, do this:

```
array7[0] = value; //or:
array7[1] = value; //or:
array7[1] = value;
```

If you want to add `value` to the array without deleting the existing values, you can do something like this:

```
//Create a new array, larger than the original.
String[] newArray7 = new String[array7.length + 1 /*1 is the minimum you are going to need, but it is better to add more. Two times the current length would be a good idea*/];

//Copy the contents of the old array into the new one.
for (int i = 0; i < array7.length; i++){
   newArray7[i] = array7[i];
}

//Set the old array's name to point to the new array object.
array7 = newArray7;
```

You can do this in a separate method, so whenever you need to re-size your array you can use it. You should know that the classes ArrayList and Vector already implement this mechanism for you, and you can `arrayList.add(string)` as much as you want.